# Create a Scalable TableView

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Right now I've created a tableview in my swift app. I'm trying to get it to create a new cell every time there is a new node in my firebase database. Or create a new cell when there is new data. Similar when on Instagram you message someone and a new chat cell appears.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: share the code what you have tried so far, and also elaborate little more about your question.

Comment: use snapchat listener to get data from firebase update your message array from that and reload the tableView.

Comment: The Firebase Getting Started guide contains a wealth of useful information. You should go through the entire guide but [Listen for child events](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data#listen_for_child_events) is a great resource. Be sure to review [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for more info on asking great questions.